# Roman and arabic page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing my thesis.
I want page numbering in roman for abstract, knowledge and arabic for the rest.

```
\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{Agradecimentos}
\input{Resumo}
\input{Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

But the number 1 , begin in "list of tables". List of tables should be in roman number. 
How i can change it ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\pagenumbering{arabic}` does not close the current page, thus if the page contains the list of tables, then the last page of it becomes numbered with arabic page numbers.

```
\listoftables
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)