# How to use pagenumbering in the document?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering

In my Master thesis, I would like to have the title page without any page number and an acknowledgments section and the table of contents with roman numbers. The rest of the document should be numbered arabic.

I have tried this, to have roman numbers for the Table of contents and normal numbers for the rest.

```
\documentclass[12pt,ngerman,openany]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{ngerman}{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\rmfamily\huge}{\textbf\thechapter.}{25pt}{\huge\textbf}
\defcaptionname{ngerman}{\lstlistingname}{Code}
\defcaptionname{ngerman}{\lstlistlistingname
}{Codeverzeichnis}

\lstloadlanguages{R} 
\lstset{% general command to set parameter(s) 
  basicstyle=\sffamily\footnotesize, % print whole listing small 
  keywordstyle=\sffamily\footnotesize\bfseries, % ubold black keywords 
  identifierstyle=, % nothing happens 
  commentstyle=\sffamily\footnotesize\slshape, % green comments 
  stringstyle=\sffamily\footnotesize, % typewriter type for strings 
  showstringspaces=false, % no special string spaces 
  numbers=left, 
  numberstyle=\sffamily\footnotesize, 
  stepnumber=1, 
  numbersep=10pt, 
  showspaces=false, 
  showtabs=false, 
  frame=lines, 
  morecomment=[l]{\%}, 
  float=htbp, 
  numberbychapter=true 
} 

\begin{document}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage


\pagenumbering{roman} 
\tableofcontents 
\clearpage 
\vspace*{75mm}
\chapter{Einleitung}
\section{Motivation}
bla bla bla
\section{Ziel}

bla bla
\chapter{Stand der Technik zur Mustererkennung}
\section{Die Zeitreihen}
bla bla
\subsection{Beschreibung}
bla bla
\subsection{Erklärung}

bla bla

\subsection{Vorhersage}
bla bla
\subsection{Kontrolle}
bla bla
\section{Feature Extraktion}
bla bla
\subsection{Autokorrelation}
\subsection{Was ist Autokorrelation?}
bla bla


\subsection{Autokorrelation und Zeitreihen}
bla bla

\subsubsection{Zeitreihe-Diagramm}

bla bla
\subsubsection{Lagged Streudiagramm}
bla bla

\subsubsection{Autocorrelation-Function (Korrelogramm)}
bla bla
\subsection{Spektralanalyse}
\subsection{Was ist Spektral-Analyse}
bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: The simple answer is to use \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}} and \setcounter{page}[1}, etc.

Answer (score 6):

`\pagenumbering{style}` changes the appearance of `\thepage` to match `style` and
resets the page count to one (`\@one`). This change in the page
number can be noticed with the shipout of the next page, which is
in fact the page currently typeset.

Now, where to put the `\pagenumbering` command? A good idea is to
place this immediately after a `chapter` command.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{standard counting}
\blindtext[8]
\chapter{roman counting}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

All works perfectly fine. But now, what does happen if we take
the same example, but use `twoside`? Package `showframe` helps us
determine what left and right pages are. The marginparcolumn is
always on the outer side.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{standard counting}
\blindtext[8]
\chapter{roman counting}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

As you may notice, two odd (right) pages follow each other,
making it very hard to bind the final output. The `chapter`
command issues a clearpage by default (`cleardoublepage` if
option `openright` is used) which isn't enough in this case. But
now, we can't issue the needed `cleardoublepage` *after* chapter
has been issued. That would make no sense. But we can use
`cleardoublepage` before `chapter`. If the `pagenumbering`
command is issued before or after `chapter` doesn't make a
difference now.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\chapter{standard counting}
\blindtext[8]
\cleardoublepage
\chapter{roman counting}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Is there anything to say about titlepages?

Yep, the standard classes and the KOMA-classes differ in their
behaviour.

```
\documentclass{report}
%\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{showframe}
\title{How does pagenumbering work?}
\author{\TeX.SX}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\chapter*{What pagenumber do we get here?}
pagenumber: \thepage
\end{document}
```

As we can see by running this example with the standard report,
the titlepage is not counted, the next page has page number 1.
The KOMA-class differs, the titlepage is counted, the next page
gets number 2.

Changing the example to `twoside` both classes number the pages
in the same way. There is a simple reason for that, odd pages are
always right-hand pages.

Why are all examples using report and its KOMA counterpart?
The behaviour described is defined in the `titlepage`
environment. `article` doesn't use a titlepage per default, books
use titlepage, but are printed `twoside` by default.

The same are working for `memoir` as well. But it should be
mentioned, that the title of a standard memoir class uses the
pagestyle `title` which is an alias for `plain`. So the titlepage
gets (visibally) numbered by default.

What about pagenumbering in articles and books? If you want to change the pagenumbering in an article, you should consider switching to a class with chapters. `book` provides the `frontmatter`, `mainmatter` and `backmatter` mechanism, taking care of pagenumbering and some other stuff.

Comment: I have read this several times and still have no idea what you're trying to tell me. after your comment on my post, I am getting an extra blank page, how to remove it. Simple question. You're always telling me to read this answer, however, I do not know what exactly is it that I should do.

Comment: @Beyond-formulas You need this blank page for later binding. If you dont have it, your document is screwed.

Comment: I don't want this page it is messing with my roman numbers! My roman numbers should start with "5" for the acknowledgement then "6" for the abstract, when this stupid empty page is appearing between my ack and abstract, my abstract starts at page "7" in roman! this looks terrible in ToC, you see? If twoside is screwing all this, why would I need it for? Why did the department place this as a sample tex file for all.... Can I replace this twoside by something else?

Comment: @Beyond-formulas With respect to that empty page, i can't say much but *Please ad a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- Link) to your latest question that led you here. About the `twoside` options, i cannot tel you why the guys in your department added that. Better ask them in person ;-)

Comment: I did a new question (minimal example), even removed the twoside and the empty page is still there... If would like to check it