# I can't get roman page numbering to work for pages before main writing section (e.g. TOC,LOF, abstract etc..)

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, lists, page-numbering, abstract

I would like to make all pages before my introduction (TOC,LOF,LOT,abstract), excluding first 3/4 pages (title page, blank page) to be roman numerals with the first page of my introduction =page 1. How can I do this?

I have tried methods posted on here but with no luck.

here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{12}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\paragraph}{%
  \@startsection{paragraph}{4}%
  {\z@}{1.2ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}{-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}%
}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}


\begin{document}
\sloppy
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}


\textsc{\Large title}\\[1.5cm]


\newpage\

\thispagestyle{empty}\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]

\vspace{15cm} 

\textsc{\large text}\\[0.5cm]
\textsc{\large even more text}\\[0.5cm]

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}


\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\thispagestyle{empty}\abstract

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

{\newgeometry{left=0.98in,right=0.98in,top=0.98in,bottom=1.5in}
%\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}



\listoffigures\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\listoftables\thispagestyle{empty}\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{2ex}\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0.5ex}

\setcounter{page}{1}
%\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\pagestyle{fancy}\fancyhead[R]{Introduction}\fancyhead[L]{Chapter 1}

\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage


\chapter{Introduction}
```

thanks,
Michael

Comment: Hi and welcome. `\pagenumbering{roman}` and later `\pagenumberin{arabic}` Thats all you need. You might want to check the difference between a `plain` and an `empty` pagestyle.

Comment: Are you trying to typeset a twosided document? Parts of your document look like you are.

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)