# How to enable the display of the page number on the first page after the Appendices title page(the page on which it says 'Appendices')?

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.6-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2014/dev) and I want to make myself a report template. The problem that I have, besides not knowing TeX/LaTeX inner workings, is with the appendix package and I shall explain: in the preamble when I import the appendix package, I provide it the options *toc* and *page*, which, as expected, add the appendix to the ToC and insert a page with the writing *Appendices* in the document at the place where I have the *appendices* environement. The problem is that on the empty page that follows the one containing the writing *Appendices*, the page number doesn't show up, as can be seen in the image below, and I would like it to. I would like to know how can I enable the page number display on the empty page.

Note: the empty page without the page number is the last one of the document as it is just a template that I want to build, but I had the same issue even when there was actual content in the Appendix.

[image: showcasing the problem with Appendices package]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}

%% make the bibliography appear in the table of contents
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

%% for the appendix
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
% toc:      put a header in the Table of Contents
% page:     puts a title page in the document where the appendix begins

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% pages with roman numbering
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}} % set the pages numbering to roman

%% import the title page
\input{ab-Title/a-TitlePage}

%% create the table of contents
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% pages with arabic numbering
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}  % set the page numbering to arabic
\setcounter{page}{1}            % reset to 1 the page numbering

%% first chapter
\chapter{Dummy Chapter}
\label{chap:Chap1}
\input{ac-Chapter1/a-Chapter1Main}



%% add the appendix
% the following commands allows one to change from english word Appendix
% to the equivalent word in another language
%\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Annexes}   % for how it should appear in the table of contents
%\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Annexes}  % for how it should appear on the separation page
\begin{appendices}
% add the appendix
\input{zy-Appendix/a-Appendix}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of package `appendix` decided that this page should be empty, but you can change this using package etoolbox.
You can read up on pagenumbers in [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192870/how-to-use-pagenumbering-in-the-document/208208#208208).
When using different languages in a document, you should use package `babel`s interface.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}
\usepackage[toc, page]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\addto\captionsngerman{
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Anh\"ange}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Anh\"ange}
}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chap@pppage}{empty}{plain}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}


\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\blinddocument
%\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{appendices}
    % add the appendix
    \blinddocument
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```