# Roman Numerals for page number in List of Abbreviations

Tags: page-numbering, nomenclature

In my report, I am using too many abbreviations. I am using nomenclature structure to create and print them in my document. I want to make roman page numbering up till list of abbreviations. Since my list of abbreviations has gone up to two pages, `LaTeX` now print arabic page number on the second page of list of abbreviations, which looks very odd to me. I want to write roman letters on the second page.

Any help?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I could imagine, that a `\clearpage` after the nomenclature list could help

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence, \clearpage worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: I think we can close this question then, since it's hard to provide the answer `\clearpage` ;-)

Comment: A `\clearpage` or `\cleardoublepage` command should *always* precede `\pagenumbering`. However, you might benefit from using the `book` class and its `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` commands that take care of the numbering business.

Comment: Related: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `\clearpage` before `\pagenumbering` solved the question, otherwise the following `\pagenumbering` command leaks backwards.

To see this, remove `\cleardoublepage` in the following example → the arabic page numbers are even in the `List of Abbrevations` although `roman` was specified before.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\listofabbreviations}{%
  \section*{Fake command}
  \blindtext[6]
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\listofabbreviations
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\end{document}
```