# Why is my page number two after my title page?

Tags: titles, page-numbering

Shouldn't it be page number one? I'm using the titlepage environment, which should make it that way. However, it shows up as page number two. And yes, this is a template I downloaded. I'll appreciate any help!

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in] {geometry} %1 inch margin on all sides
 %\usepackage{setspace} %Allows changing line spacing

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}

    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command     for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \begin{center} % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \textsc{\LARGE Lebanon High School}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your   university/college
    \textsc{\Large Global Issues Since The Fall Of The Wall}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
    %\textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    {\huge \bfseries Venice: Soon To Be Atlantis?}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft} \large
            \emph{Author:}\\
            sadf \textsc{asdf} % Your name
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        ~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright} \large
            \emph{Supervisor:} \\
            asdf \textsc{asdf} % Supervisor's Name
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}\\[4cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {\large \today}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}


 \input{Introduction} %Add in introuction file

\end{document}
```

Comment: titlepage is number 1 but not shown

Comment: It needs to be, this is by design. You have a two sided document. the titlepage (1) is on the right, the next on the left (2) and the next right is page 3. There is nothing to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the titlepage is number 1.

To start the page numbering with number 1 after the titlepage, add the following before you `\input` the content:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

Supported parameters are:

- **arabic**: arabic numbers
- **roman**: lowercase roman numbers
- **Roman**: uppercase roman numbers
- **alph**: lowercase letters
- **Alph**: uppercase letters

You can have several numbering styles in your document. For example the first pages (containing the abstract and the table of contents) can have lowercase roman numbers, while the rest of the document has arabic page numbers.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in] {geometry} %1 inch margin on all sides
 %\usepackage{setspace} %Allows changing line spacing

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{showframe} % Draw a page-layout diagram

\begin{document}

    \begin{titlepage}

    \newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}} % Defines a new command     for the horizontal lines, change thickness here

    \begin{center} % Center everything on the page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADING SECTIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \textsc{\LARGE Lebanon High School}\\[1.5cm] % Name of your   university/college
    \textsc{\Large Global Issues Since The Fall Of The Wall}\\[0.5cm] % Major heading such as course name
    %\textsc{\large Minor Heading}\\[0.5cm] % Minor heading such as course title

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \HRule \\[0.4cm]
    {\huge \bfseries Venice: Soon To Be Atlantis?}\\[0.4cm] % Title of your document
    \HRule \\[1.5cm]

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   AUTHOR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushleft} \large
            \emph{Author:}\\
            sadf \textsc{asdf} % Your name
            \end{flushleft}
        \end{minipage}
        ~
        \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            \begin{flushright} \large
            \emph{Supervisor:} \\
            asdf \textsc{asdf} % Supervisor's Name
            \end{flushright}
        \end{minipage}\\[4cm]

% If you don't want a supervisor, uncomment the two lines below and remove the section above
%\Large \emph{Author:}\\
%John \textsc{Smith}\\[3cm] % Your name

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   DATE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    {\large \today}\\[3cm] % Date, change the \today to a set date if you want to be precise

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   LOGO SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\includegraphics{Logo}\\[1cm] % Include a department/university logo - this will require the graphicx package

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \vfill % Fill the rest of the page with whitespace
    \end{center}
    \end{titlepage}
    \thispagestyle{empty} % no page numbers

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{roman} % page numbering: lowercase roman
    \tableofcontents

    \begin{abstract}    
        \blindtext[3]
    \end{abstract}

% \input{Introduction} %Add in introuction file
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic} % page numbering: arabic
    \Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: And before changing the pagenumbering, you have to use `\cleardoublepage` or the numbering will go berserk; well not the numbering, but left and right hand pages get confused. [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Comment: Assuming the contents of the roman section stop on a right hand page, there will be a left hand page missing, as odd pages are always right hand pages. Your example on the other hand, contains just one page.

Comment: Please add some content to the titlepage and load package showframe to see, that there is a cleardoublepage missing. This is a two-sided document.