# Page numbering error in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I'm preparing my thesis report. My table of contents starts from roman page number (iii) and has a total of 3 pages. But unfortunately the last page of toc shows page number (iii) again. Same is the case for the lof (3 pages). I am using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}`. I'm a beginner in LaTeX, so please help me.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{3}
\clearpage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{6}    
\chapter*{Summary}    
\clearpage

\listoffigures
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\clearpage

\listoftables
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{10}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\clearpage
```

Comment: All those instances of `\pagenumbering` and `\setcounter` are quite possibly missleading and disturbing you and your document. LaTeX is very very capable of counting pages, no need to number them yourself. I would kick out all of this lines. Please also have a look at [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  you are resetting the page counter to 3 *after* `\tableofcontents`.  once the numbering starts, you really shouldn't have to reset it until you change to arabic for the body of the document.  and issuing `\addcontentsline` for the summary *before* setting the page number will almost certainly result in the wrong page number in the toc.  it's almost always better to specify `\addcontentsline` immediately *after* the `\chapter` line for that element.

Comment: As it stands this example will fail to compile; there is only a preamble yet, filled with some content of your thesis. Can you please complete your example to a fully working, but minimal LaTeX document (starting with `\documentclass` and concluding with `\end{document}`) that showcases your error? even if you alredy got the solution.

Comment: You can also force a new page (without generating the "there is no page" error message) using \par\rule{0pt}{\textheight}

Comment: I suggest to use `\usepackage{tocbibind}` -- this will yield many of the `\addcontentsline` code above as unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't give repeated `\pagenumbering{roman}` commands: LaTeX just knows the page numbers.

Be careful to issue the `\addcontentsline` command at the right time, that is, after a new page has been started.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage % if some contents comes before
\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\chapter*{Summary}    

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\def\one{%
  \chapter{Something}
  \section{A}
  some text
  \section{A}
  some text
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Whatever}
  \end{figure}
  \section{A}
  some text
  \begin{table}
  \caption{Whatever}
  \end{table}
}
\def\many{\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one}

\many % make as much contents as to produce three pages in the toc

\end{document}
```

You can vastly simplify the input by using the `tocbibind` package and the `book` class.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tocbibind}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\pagestyle{plain} % this is what report uses

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setcounter{page}{3}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Summary}    

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\mainmatter

\def\one{%
  \chapter{Something}
  \section{A}
  some text
  \section{A}
  some text
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{Whatever}
  \end{figure}
  \section{A}
  some text
  \begin{table}
  \caption{Whatever}
  \end{table}
}
\def\many{\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one\one}

\many

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution! I rearranged the lines in the following order:

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{3}
\tableofcontents
```

Comment: This is bound to fail. Please read at [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208) why a `cleardoublepage` is always necessary to ensure a right hand page (or rather the blank page before). If you set the pagenumber to an even page, you have to ensure it really is on a left hand page. LaTeX would take care of it, but manually changing stuff means manually fixing stuff.