# Page numbering from roman to arabic

Tags: page-numbering

I have managed to use roman page numbering and now want to have arabic numbering starting on the same page as chapter 1. My code so far produce arabic number 2 on the same page as chapter 1. I already use `\setcounter` but to no effect.

```
\documentclass[10 pt, a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% The title page %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \input{titlepage}
 \pagenumbering {roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Abstract Page %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{Abstract} 

}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TOC %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter1}  %Background
\include{chapter2}  %Theory
\include{chapter3}  %Results
\include{chapter4}  %Analysis and conclusions
\include{chapter5}  %Discussions

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You have a bunch of questions and some of them have answers, but you have not accepted a single one of them and cast not a single upvote, according to your profile!

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208) or place the `\pagenumbering` command just after `\chapter{Background}`.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic}`

Comment: \cleardoublepage\pagenumbering{arabic} worked!

Comment: Christian, I know! I've tried to delete my questions but can't find a way to do it.

Comment: @Orongo: Deleting? What's the point of that?

Comment: @Christian. The question as you noticed overlapped this one. Honestly I had problems finding my Qs'. So dublicates are a reality now.