# ToC scrambles the order and page number

Tags: table-of-contents

I have LoF and LoT before my ToC. For some reason ToC present Chapter 1 before LoF, even though in the report it is the opposite. And the page number is wrong, the LoT in on iii, just after ToC.

```
\documentclass[10 pt, a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
% The title page %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \input{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage \pagenumbering {roman}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% The Abstract Page %%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\chapter*{Abstract} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% TOC %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List of Tables %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{ListofTables} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List of Figures %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{ListofFigures} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Chapters %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setcounter{page}{1}
\cleardoublepage \pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter1}  %Background
\include{chapter2}  %Theory
\include{chapter3}  %Results
\include{chapter4}  %Analysis and conclusions
\include{chapter5}  %Discussions

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} %{amsplain}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\include{Bibliography}  %Bibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about using `\include` in general; just in order to do `\listoffigures` it's certainly too much.

However, you solve all of your issues at once by removing those `\addcontentsline` commands (except the one for the abstract) and adding

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

What's the problem with your approach? That if the list of figures occupies two pages, `\addcontentsline` will refer to the second page. Also the `\include` after the list of figures has a part in the issue. With `tocbibind`, that makes LaTeX perform the `\addcontentsline` commands (automatically) at the right time, the problem is solved.

Comment: Is that a duplicate of [Abstract, Toc, lof, lot ordering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/278056)#?

Comment: tocbibind is new, I will use that. I suppose that the list will automatically update as I add figures and tables to the report?

Comment: Unfortunately with tocbibind, I still have page numbering issue for LoF. I t is technically on iv, but the numbering restart so it has i instead.

Comment: @Orongo Not in my test.

Comment: Strange... I've changed my code accordingly

Comment: \documentclass[10 pt, a4paper, leqno, oneside] {report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[swedish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[tmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

Comment: \begin{document}

 \input{titlepage}
 \cleardoublepage \pagenumbering {roman}
 
\chapter*{Abstract} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 

\tableofcontents{}
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\setcounter{page}{1}
\cleardoublepage \pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter1} %Background

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat} 
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}

Comment: @Orongo Get rid of the `\pagenumbering`, it is not needed as you should habe read in [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)