# Page numbering style

Tags: page-numbering

I want to use a "roman" page numbering in tableofcontents, listoffigures, listoftables and in the chapter called "simboli" and, then, restart the page numbering with "arabic" style in the following chapters.

I've used the following code

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\input{cap/title}
\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\input{cap/Simboli}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{cap/01}
```

The restult is that tableofcontents, listoffigures, listoftables are correctly numbered but the chapter "simboli" uses "arabic" numeration. A side-effect is that the first page of "cap/01" is the number "3" (but I can fix it).

Thanks.

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Comment: Any reason for setting the different counters to zero?

Comment: Yes. figures/tables/etc. numbering is made like "number of chapter.progressive number" (i.e. 1.4) so I need to reset the counters otherwise the first figure of chapter 2 will be 2.45 and not 2.1

Comment: Insert `\clearpage` (or `\newpage`) after `\input{cap/Simboli}` and before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: @Dalmo1991: Normally, there's no need of resetting the counters explicitly -- this is done usually when the `chapter` counter is stepped.

Comment: @egreg I'm using scrreprt

Comment: @Dalmo1991 - Glad my suggestion works for you. I've posted it as an answer, so that this query can be marked off as having been answered. :-)

Comment: @Dalmo1991 Unlike in forums, here adding “SOLVED” is not used. You tell it by accepting the answer that helped you the most, if one of them actually solved the problem (click on the check mark you should see next to the answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggested solution. The main idea is to insert `\newpage` -- `\clearpage` will work as well -- before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% ... remainder of preamble
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\input{cap/title}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\input{cap/Simboli}

\newpage % <- this is new
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{cap/01}
% ... remainder of document
\end{document}
```