# Page numbering disrupted by title page

Tags: titles, page-numbering

I am writing my Master's thesis and I have to use a pre-defined title page but I think it blocks the page numbering on the first page. I've tried

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

and

```
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

But it didn't work.. Could anyone help me on this problem ?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{UCLblue}{cmyk}{1.00,0.68,0.00,0.54}
\definecolor{EPLblue}{cmyk}{0.70,0.30,0.00,0.00}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent

\begin{document}
%% Title page
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm}
\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{EPL_TFEbanner.jpg}
\end{center}
\vspace{9pt}
\begin{flushright}
    \color{UCLblue} \fontfamily{phv} \selectfont
    {\huge title} \\
    \vspace{12pt}
    \large Dissertation presented by \\
    \textbf{nameone}
    \textbf{, nametwo}  
    \\
    \vspace{12pt} 
    for obtaining the Master's degree in \\
    \textbf{speciality} \\
    \vspace{12pt}
    Supervisor(s)\\
    \textbf{supervisor} 
    \textbf{, cosupervisor}     % Uncomment if necessary
    \\
    \vspace{12pt}
    Reader(s) \\
    \textbf{readerone, readertwo}
    \\
    \vspace{12pt}
    Academic year years \\
\end{flushright}
\vspace{9pt}
\color{EPLblue}{\rule{18.5cm}{8.25cm}}
\end{titlepage}

%% Dissertation
\chapter{Aerodynamics}
lala

% Back cover page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}       % To suppress header and footer on the back of the cover page
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm}
\vspace*{17.75cm}
\noindent \footnotesize \color{UCLblue} \fontfamily{phv} \selectfont Rue Archim\`{e}de, 1 bte L6.11.01, 1348 Louvain-la-Neuve ~ ~ \color{EPLblue} \textbf{www.uclouvain.be/epl} \\
%\vspace*{6pt}
\color{EPLblue}{\rule{18.5cm}{8.25cm}}

\end{document}
```

To compile, you need to use [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WRiY.jpg).

Comment: Please change your document to the **compilable** minimum. The `titlepage` environment sets the page number always either to zero or to one, depending on the `titlepage` option. (I can't remember which one is in action here)

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Comment: Christian Hupfer: Sorry, I changed my document, it is compilable now. The problem is not on the title page but on the first page after the title page: there is no number at all on this page.

Comment: Now, let me ask, what do you want? You want to have the page-number printed on the ttlepage?

Comment: I'd like to have the page number printed on the first page _after_ the title page (the page on which there is "Chapter 1...")

Comment: Use `\restoregeometry` *after* `\end{titlepage}`.

Comment: Alternatively, stop using the geometry hack, build your titlepage standalone and just include the ready pdf as is described in [title page examples](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/titlepageExamples).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\restoregeometry` after the `titlepage:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{UCLblue}{cmyk}{1.00,0.68,0.00,0.54}
\definecolor{EPLblue}{cmyk}{0.70,0.30,0.00,0.00}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%% Title page
\begin{titlepage}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm}
\begin{center}
 \includegraphics[scale=1]{EPL_TFE2.jpg}
\end{center}
\vspace{9pt}
\begin{flushright}
 \color{UCLblue} \fontfamily{phv} \selectfont
 {\huge title} \\
 \vspace{12pt}
 \large Dissertation presented by \\
 \textbf{nameone}
 \textbf{, nametwo}
 \\
 \vspace{12pt}
 for obtaining the Master's degree in \\
 \textbf{speciality} \\
 \vspace{12pt}
 Supervisor(s)\\
 \textbf{supervisor}
 \textbf{, cosupervisor} % Uncomment if necessary
 \\
 \vspace{12pt}
 Reader(s) \\
 \textbf{readerone, readertwo}
 \\
 \vspace{12pt}
 Academic year years \\
\end{flushright}
\vspace{9pt}
\color{EPLblue}{\rule{18.5cm}{8.25cm}}
\end{titlepage}

\restoregeometry
\chapter{Aerodynamics}
lala

% Back cover page
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty} % To suppress header and footer on the back of the cover page
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,left=1.25cm,right=1.25cm}
\vspace*{17.75cm}
\noindent \footnotesize \color{UCLblue} \fontfamily{phv} \selectfont Rue Archim\`{e}de, 1 bte L6.11.01, 1348 Louvain-la-Neuve ~ ~ \color{EPLblue} \textbf{www.uclouvain.be/epl} \\
%\vspace*{6pt}
\color{EPLblue}{\rule{18.5cm}{8.25cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But when I don't use the specific title page I was given, the first page of the chapter is numbered.

Comment: The example given has *only* right hand pages.

Comment: It is is not what I obtain on compiling. But perhaps do you mean you *print* single-sided?

Comment: I am extremely confused by the question, the answer and the comments.

Comment: @Johannes_B:  Sorry;, I didn't notice the comment on the right-hand pages  was yours, not the O.P.'s. Did you mean the report class is one-sided by default?

Comment: Yes, it is ;-) `\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper,10pt,oneside,onecolumn,final,openany}`

Comment: However, that doesn't explain why at the bottom of the first page, the page number seems to be replaced with text.

Comment: title page is empty, on the second page (\thepage=1) the number is pushed down because changing the page geometry mid document is risky business and fails here.

Comment: I see. It's a simple matter of adding `\restoregeometry`.