# How to fix messed up page numbering in thesis

Tags: page-numbering

In writing my MS thesis I have to add Certificate of Examination and declaration by student pages and I tried to add them by using `\chapter*`. But the problem is page numberings is now messed up. In the following code CoE, Declaration and acknowledgment are getting numbering 2,3 and 4 resp. then numbering starts again from Introduction being 1 and first page of thesis being 2.

I want numbering to start from the first chapter. I do not want any numbering on CoE, or acknowledgment or Introduction etc. How can I do it?

```
    \documentclass[twoside, <further options>]{report}
    \usepackage[inner=1.25in, outer=1in, vmargin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{sectsty}
    \usepackage{setspace} 
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{centernot}
    \setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
    \parindent=0pt

    \doublespacing
    \begin{document}
    \title {BACBAC}
    \author{Bhaskar Vashishth}




    \date{\today}
    \maketitle

    \clearpage
    \allsectionsfont{\centering}



    \chapter*{Certificate of Examination}This is to certify that the dissertation titled “xyz”
    submitted by Mr. gghj (Reg. No. 1234) for the partial fulfilment
    of MS degree programme of the Institute, has been examined
    by the thesis committee duly appointed by the Institute. The committee
    finds the work done by the candidate satisfactory and recommends that the
    report be accepted.
    \chapter*{Declaration}The work presented in this dissertation has been carried out by me under
    the guidance of Prof. abc at the ISRM
    This work has not been submitted in part or in full for a degree, a diploma,
    or a fellowship to any other university or institute. Whenever contributions
    of others are involved, every effort is made to indicate this clearly, with due
    acknowledgement of collaborative research and discussions. This thesis is a
    bonafide record of original work done by me and all sources listed within
    have been detailed in the bibliography.

    \chapter*{Acknowlegment} Thanks
    \abstract{lipsum.  
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \cleardoublepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    \chapter*{Introduction} Something
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \chapter{XYZXY}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Try adding `\pagenumbering{gobble}` after your `\maketitle`

Comment: It works that CoE, acknowledgemnt etc has no numbering but still numbering starts from introduction and not from chap 1

Comment: What if you put `\setcounter{page}{1}` after `\chapter{XYZXY}`?

Comment: then both introduction and chapters first page has numbering 1 and after that its normal

Comment: **Introduction then Chapter1 then pagenumbering** [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bunch of `\thispagestyle{empty}` after `\chapter` isn't helpful,since `\chapter` uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` (hardcoded). I've changed this by using a patch and referring to a pagestyle hidden in a macro name, which can be redefined later on.

Also `\pagenumbering{arabic}` sets the page counter to `1` already, there's no need to use `\setcounter{page}{1}` again.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[inner=1.25in, outer=1in, vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{centernot}

\usepackage{xpatch}

  \xpatchcmd{\chapter}{%
    \thispagestyle{plain}%
  }{%
    \thispagestyle{\chapterfirstpagestyle}
  }{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failed!}}

\newcommand{\chapterfirstpagestyle}{empty}



\setlength\parskip{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\parindent=0pt

\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\title {BACBAC}
\author{Bhaskar Vashishth}




\date{\today}
\maketitle

\clearpage
\allsectionsfont{\centering}
\pagestyle{empty}


\chapter*{Certificate of Examination}This is to certify that the dissertation titled “xyz”
submitted by Mr. gghj (Reg. No. 1234) for the partial fulfilment
of MS degree programme of the Institute, has been examined
by the thesis committee duly appointed by the Institute. The committee
finds the work done by the candidate satisfactory and recommends that the
report be accepted.
\chapter*{Declaration}The work presented in this dissertation has been carried out by me under
the guidance of Prof. abc at the ISRM
This work has not been submitted in part or in full for a degree, a diploma,
or a fellowship to any other university or institute. Whenever contributions
of others are involved, every effort is made to indicate this clearly, with due
acknowledgement of collaborative research and discussions. This thesis is a
bonafide record of original work done by me and all sources listed within
have been detailed in the bibliography.

\chapter*{Acknowlegment} Thanks
\abstract{lipsum.  
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter*{Introduction} Something
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\renewcommand{\chapterfirstpagestyle}{plain}

\chapter{XYZXY}
\end{document}
```