# Pagenumber change; causing margin (and marginnotes) to switch sides

Tags: margins, page-numbering, marginnote

I am using `\documentclass{article}` to formulate an `a4paper` in `twoside` mode; Every thing is fine ... Well nearly, there is a small glitch somewhere in the standard LaTeX defaults between the page numbering function and the margin setup.

Here is a simplified version of the problem, initial pages are numbered with {roman} numerals; The main bulk of the document is then enumerated with {arabic} numerals.

Between the roman and the arabic numerals; The margin weight for the double page spread is shifting from outer to inner, or vice versa; The problem arises if the format change is made on an even page as it resets the count to an odd number.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Jabberwocky}
    \author{Lewis Carroll}
    \date{1871}
\maketitle

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
This is an unfathomably long line of relative yet diminutive sense, such that
the totality of the page is spread with ink.

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Twas brillig}
`Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

\section{Beware the Jabberwock}
"Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!"

\section{He took his vorpal sword}
He took his vorpal sword in hand:
Long time the manxome foe he sought --
So rested he by the Tumtum tree,
And stood awhile in thought.

\section{And, as in uffish}
And, as in uffish thought he stood,
The Jabberwock, with eyes of flame,
Came whiffling through the tulgey wood,
And burbled as it came!

\newpage
\section{One, two! One, two!}
One, two! One, two! And through and through
The vorpal blade went snicker-snack!
He left it dead, and with its head
He went galumphing back.

\section{And, has thou slain}
"And, has thou slain the Jabberwock?
Come to my arms, my beamish boy!
O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!'
He chortled in his joy.

\section{Twas brillig}
`Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe. 

\end{document}
```

And a screen shot of the pdf; Notice the difference in width of the juxtaposed margin between the title page and the content page i, and again between the content and page 1:

[image]

Comment: We don't need to see your preamble in its current form (as it contains a lot of packages that are irrelevant to the problem). Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates your problem? Click on the mentioned link and please read the post.

Comment: @Werner Thank you for the link. Here is a more concise rendition of the problem. Upon writing this it occurs to me that there is a number reset command, perhaps this would reset the margin too?

Comment: It's perfectly normal: LaTeX decides that a page is right or left based on the value of the `page` counter; you have page “i” which is a right-hand page, followed by page “1”, which is again a right-hand page. You need `\cleardoublepage` (so as to create an empty page) when switching from Roman to Arabic numbers.

Comment: @egreg Thank you; This is not really solving the issue as my document starts with a title page that has `pagenumbering{gobble}`. Followed by an even number of roman numerated pages, and then the document starts. I think that using the `\cleardoublepage` will cause a problem in the double side print; thank you for your consideration.

Comment: I suppose I could just skip that page in the pdf print, there must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I can't recommend using `\pagenumbering{gobble}`. But nobody prevents you from setting an even page number (say 0) in the title page. Margins should be adjusted only in the title page, but it's easier.

Comment: @egreg Ah yes and I have just remembered that I am using a blank page after the title page too (by way of a cheeky white full stop!), so I could have used your `\cleardoublepage` here, I will try this and also your suggestion for reseting the page number to 0 ... Hum, might be getting the picture now.

Comment: When I start at page 0 the margins are inversed through the entire document; I was wondering if there is a command that will just switch over the odd/even.

Comment: [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, \pagenumbering resets numbering to one.

Standard packages put odd numbers in recto pages and even in verso pages (recto = front and even = back for left-to-right languages).

You can sustitute \pagenumbering{arabic} with something like:

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
```

It renews command \thepage to arabic format without reseting page counter.

If you want to put an specific number from one page use:

```
\setcounter{page}{7} % sustitute 7 for the number you want.
```

Comment: This will work for now, thank you. It would be nice to reset the numerals to 1 without the margin jumping about though.

Comment: Oh , firstly please let me apologize to you, it would seem that there is a bug in the stack exchange messaging protocol; I am unable to signal you from with this response due to some factor in-regard to your choice of screen name

Comment: Darn, just missed the 5min editing limit - These text boxes are a pain when  used to writing with vim, continuing on from the above ... Although your response has been useful to me in understanding why I can not achieve that which I wish to achieve, however; I am not currently using your solution. To my mind the issue at hand is not yet solved and is worthy of a little further explanation as to why; for the purpose of clarification before closing the thread.

Comment: I am just wondering if there is not some tradition in book typesetting and binding that dictates that the first numbered page is always on the right hand side; my problem was caused by trying to start the numbering, with page one on the left; Mine is an article, with ordered subsections which take advantage graphically of the double spread, placing similar subjects together on opposing pages to make them easer to study; I think that TeX is my solution and that I need to learn more about the difference between TeX and LaTeX ...

Comment: I think LaTeX is better solution because you have a lot of packages ready for use. In TeX you have to do everything by hand. I read the companion guide to the memoir package. https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/memdesign?lang=en It gives a lot of information about typesetting practices.

Comment: Still not getting your name appear as confirmation of a found link, Are you receiving a notice at your end? Thank you for the link, it looks to be a valuable resource. You are quite right, and in particular I am using the Xe Latex package for Sanskritic fonts ... no doubt that a lot of work was required in making the devanāgarī script legable.

Comment: xelatex is my usual compiler because easy system font usage and utf8 by default. Changed my alias to shosta a few minutes ago. I added some explanation to the answer too. Perhaps that could help.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my initial conundrum using a selection of the advice given in the comments and reply above; Perhaps this will help others to quickly resolve this leap in understanding that is quite necessary in avoiding teething problems when staring out with the LaTeX package.

As explained above the numbering system is inextricably linked to the double sided page printing layout; As such, this effects the placement of  the left and right margins, if they are not of equal width and also the placement of margin notes when they are included. To resolve this issue there are various differing techniques, of which; The following has worked well for me.

First set the title page to `\pagenumbering{gobble}` and the page number to `\setcounter{page}{0}`; The prologue and contents section is then enumerated with roman numerals; Forced to finish upon an even numbered page, by way of the `\cleardoublepage` command. The actual content is numbered using indic numerals, by using the `\pagenumbering{arabic}` command; This gives the desired result. In essence; each segment must end upon an even number, before the page count is reset to one, if this is not done; The margins switch sides. In my screen capture example there is included an image, which achieves the same; Note that the `\cleardoublepage` command remains in the code but that it does not add a page when it is not required.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\title{Jabberwocky}
    \author{Lewis Carroll}
    \date{1871}
\maketitle

\newpage
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\cleardoublepage

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Twas brillig}
`Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.

\section{Beware the Jabberwock}
"Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!"

\section{He took his vorpal sword}
He took his vorpal sword in hand:
Long time the manxome foe he sought --
So rested he by the Tumtum tree,
And stood awhile in thought.

\section{And, as in uffish}
And, as in uffish thought he stood,
The Jabberwock, with eyes of flame,
Came whiffling through the tulgey wood,
And burbled as it came!

\newpage
\section{One, two! One, two!}
One, two! One, two! And through and through
The vorpal blade went snicker-snack!
He left it dead, and with its head
He went galumphing back.

\section{And, has thou slain}
"And, has thou slain the Jabberwock?
Come to my arms, my beamish boy!
O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay!'
He chortled in his joy.

\section{Twas brillig}
`Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe. 

\end{document}
```

The finished result: (with image added)

[image]

If you require that the larger margin be placed upon the other side of each page; this can be achieved by omitting the `\setcounter{page}{0}` from the title page and including a `\cleardoublepage`, a dedication, or perhaps an image instead.