# Using Openright and twoside with multiple page numbering styles

Tags: double-sided

So I am getting the shell of a document ready and I have noticed a problem with openright in the report document class. In this document I have preliminary pages and my main document pages. The preliminary pages are numbered using roman numbering where as the main pages are arabic. Openright seems to allocate odd numbered pages as right pages based on the pagnumbering used rather than the actual page that the PDF is on. So when my pagenumbering is reset when switching to arabic openright and twoside stops working and produces two "odd" pages in a row if there are an odd number of pages in the preliminary section.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\chapter{Prelim 1}
Text
\chapter{Prelim 2}
More text
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Main 1}
Even more text
\chapter{Main 2}
I can't believe there is this much text...
\end{document}
```

Above is an example of what I mean, if you compile that you will notice that the Prelim 2 and Main 1 chapters are on consecutive pages. Is there any way to force openright and twoside to abide by the page count rather than the pagenumbering?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `\cleardoublepage` instead of `\newpage`.  This inserts new pages until you end up on a recto page again.  It uses the page count and not the page numbering.

Comment: your readers will not be expecting even numbered pages on the right of a 2 page spread so best to use the printed page number rather than an internal count. use `\cleardoublepage` to keep them in sync as Henri suggests.

Comment: Use the `book` class; issue `\frontmatter` instead of `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\mainmatter` instead of `\pagenumbering{arabic}`. No `\newpage` is necessary. If you want to keep the `report` style for headers, issue `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Place `\pagenumbering` *after* you call `\chapter` as seen in  [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208)

Answer (score 4):

As egreg mentioned above, I have changed to `book` and am using `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` to handle the numbering.

Thanks a lot!