# Roman and arabic numbering with report

Tags: formatting, page-numbering

I am writing a thesis using the report class. I want to have up until the introduction in Roman numberals, This is fine and I got it to work using previous questions. However, I am having trouble getting the arabic numbering to start at page 1 on the introduction. If I put     `\include{tex/Introduction}\pagenumbering{arabic}` the introduction starts on page X while if I use `\pagenumbering{arabic}\include{tex/Introduction}` the introduction starts on page 2. How do I get the introduction to start on page 1?

Comment: `\setcounter{page}{1}` ?

Comment: `\pagenumbering` does always reset the page counter! `\include` will always use a new page first. Use `\pagenumbering{arabic}` inside the `tex/Introduction` file

Comment: Another way to obtain it: `\pagenumbering{arabic}\addtocounterpage{-1}\include{tex/Introduction}`.

Comment: using `\pagenumbering` inside `tex/Introduction` worked. Thanks.

Comment: it's rather a mystery why `report` is chosen in a case like this rather than `book`.  there are very few differences, and `book` has the benefit of defining `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\backmatter`, which makes things like this so much simpler.

Comment: Report is the standard we use for thesis and there is no point changing now.

Comment: I would say this is a duplicate of [How to use pagenumbering in the document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192870)

Answer (score 1):

I see no problem with the following:

```
\begin{filecontents}{fungie-intro.tex}
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents

\listoftables

\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{fungie-intro}

\end{document}
```

You probably missed `\cleardoublepage` before `\pagenumbering{arabic}`.

[image]