# Page numbering in top corner

Tags: page-numbering

I want to number my pages in the top corner, left or right - it depends on the side of book, the left page in book should have number on the left side and the right page on the right side. It works now only for one side (right or left).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Wnich document class do you employ, which formatting-related options do you pass to the document class, and do you load any packages, such as `geometry`, which affect the page layout?

Comment: Packages like `fancyhdr`, `titleps` or `scrlayer-scrpage` let you customize the page headers (and footers). But all your efforts will be in vain, if your document is set up to be one-sided.

Answer (score 1):

New version: You can use `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`. And `\ohead*{\pagemark}` for outer pagemarks.

It works if your document is set up to be `twoside`.

[image]

Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ohead*{\pagemark}% alternativ \ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Titel
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}                 %counter =1
first page \newpage
second page \newpage
... next page
\end{document}
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Accepted(old packages):

You can use `\usepackage{scrpage2}`. For example `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`. Set pagemarks inside or outside: `\ihead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}` or `\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}`.

It works if your document ist set up to be `twoside`. 
[image]
Example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} % headline and footnote style:scrpage2-package
\clearscrheadings % clear headlines
\clearscrheadfoot % clear footnote
\ihead[\pagemark]{\pagemark} 
%\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark} %alternative

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
Titel
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\setcounter{page}{1}                 %counter =1
first page \newpage
second page \newpage
... next page
\end{document}
```

Comment: `scrpage2`  is obsolete. package `scrlayer-scrpage` is the current package to use.

Comment: The titlepage is the one with the page counter one. Please load package  `showframe`  to see that the numbering is completely messed up. See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192870/how-to-use-pagenumbering-in-the-document