# How to put the numbers of the pages at the top of each page?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

Could you please help me find how I could put the numbers of the pages on the top of each page as is used in `classicthesis`? This is my mwe :

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum

\chapter{Another chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you just want the page numbers on top you could have a look at `scrlayer-scrpage` and its commands to alter pagestyle.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/353331/124842

Comment: @Schweinebacke Where in her question does domi say she wants to use classicthesis???

Comment: I am not about to change anything into classicthesis. I just want to have the same layout for the pages headers. @TeXnician : your suggestion does not work with me. Do I have to remove my scrbook class and set it with scrlayer-scrpage?

Comment: @domi: `scrlayer-scrpage` is a package not a class. See the KOMA-Script manual (scrguide.pdf or scrguien.pdf) for more information.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip: Tag `classicthesis` had been used.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
               twoside=semi,%
               headings=small,%
               chapterprefix=true,%
               listof=flat]%
{scrbook}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% See scrguien.pdf, chapter 5
\ihead{\headmark}% running head at the inner edge of the page head
\ohead*{\pagemark}% page number at the outer edge of the page head (plain pages too)
\ofoot*{}% no page number at the outer edge of the page footer (plain pages too)
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape\small}%changed to small caps in headers
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: two pages]