# Biblatex doesn't work - no bibliography printed

Tags: biblatex, biber

### SOLUTION

Don't use `refsection=chapter` in biblatex options.
Thanks to user [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr).

### What I'm doing

I am writing my thesis with LaTeX and encountered a huge problem. The bibliography isn't working.

I am using biblatex with biber. (Biber is installed on my machine.)

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
```

I am doing citing with custom commands like

```
\newcommand{\citeindirect}[2]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S.~#2.}]}
```

I think I'm doing the right compilation steps: (compile, biber, compile, show).
As you can see in the picture, the citations work and my footnotes are printed with the correct references.
[image]

### The Problem

The links don't work. They all point to the first page of the document.
Printing the biliography doesn't work at all. **Nothing**.

```
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis, heading=bibnumbered]
```

I created a minimal working example with the same file structure that I use in my thesis. I removed many packages and all the text. The only thing that is the same if the chapter/sectiopn structure and alle the citations.
As expected, the bib doesn't work. Some coworkers checked this on their machine and it's the same result.

Now some unexplainable things happen:
Wenn I comment some of the inputs like `\input{chapter}`, the bib works.
That makes no sense, since these files only contains citations and nothing else.

### Minimal 'Working' Example

**EDIT:**

You have two files: "thesis.tex" and "bib.bib".

*thesis.tex*

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext, mathrsfs, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false, pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage[bottom, hang]{footmisc}
\setlength\footnotemargin{10pt}
\usepackage{breakcites}

% Zitieren
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% bib einbinden
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
   andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},
}

\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{8000}

% Schrift
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % scaleable font, necessary for Windows
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

% Formatierung der Titelseite
\usepackage[margin = 12pt]{caption}
\usepackage{titling}
\pagestyle{headings}

% Anhang
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

% ######################################
% Zitate
% ######################################

% Fußnoten
\setlength{\footnotesep}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{1cm}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\newcommand*{\fullref}[1]{\hyperref[{#1}]{\autoref*{#1} --  \nameref*{#1}}}

% indirektes Zitieren
\newcommand{\citeindirectNoPage}[1]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}]}

\newcommand{\citeindirectNoPageDouble}[2]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1})},\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#2}:~\citeauthor{#2}, \citetitle{#2} (\citeyear{#2})}]}

\newcommand{\citeMixedDouble}[3]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S. #2},\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#3}:~\citeauthor{#3}, \citetitle{#3} (\citeyear{#3})}]}

\newcommand{\citeindirect}[2]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S.~#2.}]}

\newcommand{\citeindirectdouble}[4]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S.~#2. und \cite{#1}:\citeauthor{#3}, \citetitle{#3} (\citeyear{#3}), S.~#4}]}

% direktes Zitieren
\newcommand{\citedirect}[2]{[\footnote{\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S.~#2.}]}

\newcommand{\citedirectNoPage}[1]{[\footnote{\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}]}

% Zitieren einer Abbildung
\newcommand{\citeabb}[2]{[\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S.~#2.]}

% Zitieren einer Quelle aus dem Internet
\newcommand{\citeinternet}[2]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), S.~#2.}]}

\newcommand{\citeinternetdata}[1]{[\footnote{\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1})}]}

\newcommand{\citeapache}[1]{[\footnote{\cite{#1}:~\citetitle{#1} (\hyperlink{\citeurl{#1}}{https://spark.apache.org})}]}

\newcommand{\citeinternetarticle}[2]{[\footnote{Vgl.~\cite{#1}:~\citeauthor{#1}, \citetitle{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), #2}]}

% ######################################
% /Zitate
% ######################################

\addbibresource{bib.bib}

% ###############################################################
% Dokument
% ###############################################################

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    
    % Titelseite
    \clearpage        
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{titlepage}        
        ...
    \end{titlepage}

    % Abstract
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \chapter{Abstract}

    % Inhaltsverzeichnis
    \clearpage
    \begingroup
        \hypersetup{hidelinks}
        \tableofcontents
    \endgroup
    
    \clearpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

        \citeinternetdata{bundeskartellamt2013kraftstoff}
    
            \clearpage
            \chapter{...}
            
                \section{...}
                \citeindirectNoPage{klosgen1996explora} und Wrobel~\citeindirectNoPage{wrobel1997algorithm}\citeindirectNoPage{siebes1995data}
                
                    \subsection{...}
                    \citeindirect{Herrera2011}{499}\citeindirect{atzmueller2006sdmap}{3}\citeindirect{atzmueller2015advanced}{3}\citeindirect{Herrera2011}{499~ff}\citeindirect{atzmueller2015advanced}{6}
                    
                \section{...}
                \citeindirectNoPageDouble{apachesparkcluster}{soutierblog}

            \clearpage
            \chapter{...}
            
            \citetitle{Herrera2011}  \citeauthor{Herrera2011}\citeindirect{Herrera2011}{496~ff}\citetitle{lavravc2004subgroup} \citeauthor{lavravc2004subgroup} 
            \citeauthor{Herrera2011}\citeauthor{lavravc2004subgroup}
            
                \par \citetitle{atzmueller2015advanced}
                \citeMixedDouble{norvig1992paradigms}{211~ff}{lowerre1976harpy}
                \citeindirectNoPage{han2000mining}
                \citeindirectNoPage{atzmueller2006sdmap}
            
                \section{...}
                
                \citeindirect{atzmueller2006sdmap}{5~f}
                \citeindirectNoPage{Klosgen:2002:HDM}
                \citeindirect{atzmueller2006sdmap}{1~f}
            
                \section{...}
                \label{sec:literatur_qf}
                \citeindirect{atzmueller2015advanced}{4~f}\citeauthor{pieters2010subgroup}\citetitle{pieters2010subgroup}
                \citeindirect{pieters2010subgroup}{6~f}
                \citeindirectNoPage{klosgen1996explora}
                \citeindirect{atzmueller2015advanced}{5}
                \citeindirectNoPage{trajkovski2011functional}
            
                \subsection{...}
                \citeauthor{trajkovski2011functional}\citeindirectNoPage{trajkovski2011functional}
                \citeindirect{pieters2010subgroup}{8}
                
                \section{...}
                    \subsection{...}
                    \citeindirect{saake2014algorithmen}{455~ff}
            
                    \subparagraph{...}
        
            \clearpage
            \chapter{...}
            
                \section{...}
                
                \begin{quote}
                    \citeinternetdata{bundeskartellamt2013kraftstoff}
                \end{quote}
                \citeinternetdata{tankerkoenig}
                
                \section{...}
            
            \clearpage
            \chapter{...}
            
            \section{...}
            
            \paragraph{...}
            \section{...}
            
                \subsection{...}
                
                \paragraph{...}
                \subsection{...}
                    \subsubsection{...}
                    \paragraph{...}
                    \subsubsection{...}
                    
            \clearpage
            \chapter{...}
            
            \section{...}
            
        \clearpage
        \chapter{...}

    \begin{appendices}
        \clearpage
        \markright{\MakeUppercase{\textit{Appendix -- Literaturverzeichnis}}}
        \printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis, heading=bibnumbered]

        \clearpage
        \chapter{Second Appendix}
        \markright{\MakeUppercase{\textit{Appendix -- Second Appendix}}}
        \section{...}
    \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

*bib.bib*

```
@Inbook{atzmueller2006sdmap,
    author={Atzmueller, Martin and Puppe, Frank},
    editor={F{\"u}rnkranz, Johannes and Scheffer, Tobias and Spiliopoulou, Myra},
    title={SD-Map -- A Fast Algorithm for Exhaustive Subgroup Discovery},
    bookTitle={Knowledge Discovery in Databases: PKDD 2006: 10th European Conference on Principles and Practice of Knowledge Discovery in Databases Berlin, Germany, September 18-22, 2006 Proceedings},
    year={2006},
    publisher={Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    address={Berlin, Heidelber},
    pages={6--17},
    isbn={978-3-540-46048-0},
    doi={10.1007/11871637_6},
    url={http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/11871637_6}
}

@article{atzmueller2015advanced,
    title={Subgroup Discovery -- Advanced Review},
    author={Atzmueller, Martin},
    journal={Wiley Interdisciplinary Reviews: Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
    volume={5},
    number={1},
    pages={35--49},
    year={2015},
    publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}

@Article{Herrera2011,
    author="Herrera, Franciso
    and Carmona, Crist{\'o}bal Jos{\'e}
    and Gonz{\'a}lez, Pedro
    and del Jesus, Mar{\'i}a Jos{\'e}",
    title="An overview on subgroup discovery: foundations and applications",
    journal="Knowledge and Information Systems",
    year="2011",
    volume="29",
    number="3",
    pages="495--525",
    abstract="Subgroup discovery is a data mining technique which extracts interesting rules with respect to a target variable.
    An important characteristic of this task is the combination of predictive and descriptive induction.
    An overview related to the task of subgroup discovery is presented.
    This review focuses on the foundations, algorithms, and advanced studies together with the applications of subgroup discovery presented throughout the specialised bibliography.",
    issn="0219-3116",
    doi="10.1007/s10115-010-0356-2",
    url="http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10115-010-0356-2"
}

@book{Klosgen:2002:HDM,
    editor = {Kl\"{o}sgen, Willi and Zytkow, Jan M.},
    title = {Handbook of Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
    chapter = {16.3: Subgroup Discovery},
    year = {2002},
    isbn = {0-19-511831-6},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press, Inc.},
    address = {New York, NY, USA},
} 

@inproceedings{klosgen1996explora,
    title={Explora: A multipattern and multistrategy discovery assistant},
    author={Kl{\"o}sgen, Willi},
    booktitle={Advances in knowledge discovery and data mining},
    pages={249--271},
    year={1996},
    organization={American Association for Artificial Intelligence}
}

@inproceedings{wrobel1997algorithm,
    title={An algorithm for multi-relational discovery of subgroups},
    author={Wrobel, Stefan},
    booktitle={European Symposium on Principles of Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery},
    pages={78--87},
    year={1997},
    organization={Springer}
}

@inproceedings{siebes1995data,
    title={Data Surveying: Foundations of an Inductive Query Language},
    author={Siebes, Arno},
    booktitle={KDD},
    pages={269--274},
    year={1995}
}

@misc{uci1996,
    author = {Ronny Kohavi and Barry Becker},
    year = {1996},
    title = {UCI Machine Learning Repository - Census Income Data Set},
    url ={http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Census+Income},
    institution = {Silicon Graphics, Data Mining and Visualization}
}

@misc{bundeskartellamt2013kraftstoff,
    title={Markttransparenzstelle für Kraftstoffe},
    author={Bundeskartellamt},
    institution={Bundeskartellamt},
    year={2016},
    month={11},
    day={10},
    url={http://www.bundeskartellamt.de/DE/Wirtschaftsbereiche/Mineral%C3%B6l/MTS-Kraftstoffe/mtskraftstoffe_node.html}
}

@misc{tankerkoenig,
    title={Historische Benzinpreisdaten},
    author={Tankerkönig API},
    institution={Bundeskartellamt},
    year={2016},
    month={11},
    day={17},
    url={https://creativecommons.tankerkoenig.de/#history}
}

@misc{manfrin2016plz,
    author = {Andread Manfrin},
    title = {Database-Marketing: Postleitzahlen zum Download},
    institution={IT Consulting Freiburg},
    year={2016},
    month={11},
    day={23},
    url = {http://www.manfrin-it.com/postleitzahlen/plz.html},
}

@book{saake2014algorithmen,
    title={Algorithmen und Datenstrukturen: Eine Einf{\"u}hrung mit Java},
    author={Saake, G. and Sattler, K.U.},
    isbn={9783864914393},
    url={https://books.google.de/books?id=txRMDAAAQBAJ},
    year={2014},
    publisher={dpunkt.verlag}
}

@book{edelkamp2011heuristic,
    title={Heuristic Search: Theory and Applications},
    author={Edelkamp, S. and Schroedl, S.},
    isbn={9780080919737},
    url={https://books.google.de/books?id=3k5MVjKzBP4C},
    year={2011},
    publisher={Elsevier Science}
}

@inproceedings{pieters2010subgroup,
    title={Subgroup discovery in ranked data, with an application to gene set enrichment},
    author={Pieters, Barbara FI and Knobbe, Arno and Dzeroski, Sa{\v{s}}o},
    booktitle={Proceedings preference learning workshop (PL 2010) at ECML PKDD},
    volume={10},
    pages={1--18},
    year={2010}
}

@online{fpgrowth_1.3.1,
    title = {{Apache Spark} MLlib -- Frequent Pattern Mining 1.3.1},
    url = {https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html},
    subtitle = {FP-growth},
    language = {english},
    version = {1.3.1},
    organization = {Apache},
    urldate = {2017-02-03},
    editor = {Apache Foundation}
}

@book{norvig1992paradigms,
    title={Paradigms of artificial intelligence programming: case studies in Common LISP},
    author={Norvig, Peter},
    year={1992},
    publisher={Morgan Kaufmann}
}

@article{lavravc2004subgroup,
    title={Subgroup discovery with CN2-SD},
    author={Lavra{\v{c}}, Nada and Kav{\v{s}}ek, Branko and Flach, Peter and Todorovski, Ljup{\v{c}}o},
    journal={Journal of Machine Learning Research},
    volume={5},
    number={Feb},
    pages={153--188},
    year={2004}
}

@inproceedings{han2000mining,
    title={Mining frequent patterns without candidate generation},
    author={Han, Jiawei and Pei, Jian and Yin, Yiwen},
    booktitle={ACM Sigmod Record},
    volume={29},
    number={2},
    pages={1--12},
    year={2000},
    organization={ACM}
}

@book{trajkovski2011functional,
  title={Functional interpretation of gene expression data},
  author={Trajkovski, Igor},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Lap Lambert Academic Publ}
}

@online{apachespark,
    title = {Spark Overview},
    url = {http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/},
    language = {english},
    organization = {Apache},
    urldate = {2017-02-12},
    date={2016-12-28},
    author={Apache Foundation}
}

@online{apachesparkcluster,
    title = {Spark Cluster Overview},
    url = {http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html},
    language = {english},
    organization = {Apache},
    urldate = {2017-02-13},
    date={2016-12-28},
    author={Apache Foundation}
}

@online{soutierblog,
    title = {Einführung in Apache Spark},
    url = {http://www.soutier.de/blog/2015/03/11/apache-spark-intro/},
    author = {Marius Soutier},
    language = {german},
    urldate = {2017-02-12},
    date={2015-03-11}
}

@article{lowerre1976harpy,
    title={The HARPY speech recognition system},
    author={Lowerre, Bruce T},
    year={1976}
}
```

If everything goes right, there should be two chapters in my appendex. The first is the bibliography and the second is something else. If it is not working, there is only one chapter in the appendex.

Thanks in advance!
I would really appreciate any help.

---

In case it helps:

> Tested on: Windows 10 Professional
>
> This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (MiKTeX 2.9.6200 64-bit)
>
> biber version: 2.7

(and on Ubuntu/Debian with TeXLive 2016)

---

### SOLUTION

As [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) pointed out: removing `refsection=chapter` from biblatex options (and moving `hyperref`) solves the issue.

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Why can't you post the MWE here? If you need to tell us the content of three files or whatever, just do that. You are more likely to get help if you post it here. Also, your question should remain useful to future readers, which is hard if there is no code here.

Comment: I can't even guess, looking at your repository, which is the main `.tex` file. Even if you need more than one `\input{}`, do you really need this many `.tex` files? Consider using the `filecontents` environment before `\documentclass{}` to include them into a single file.

Comment: But remove `refsection=chapter`. If you are trying to print the bibliography as a chapter at the end, you definitely don't want this.

Comment: I'm trying to do it with filecontents now. "bachelorarbeit.tex" is the main, as stated in the repository description. I'll update the question in a few seconds.

Comment: Why do I not want to print the bib as a chapter? It looks like this when it's working: Appendix A: Bib; Appendix B: other

Comment: I updated the question with an MWE.

Comment: Just remove `refsection=chapter` and load `hyperref` last. Please read the documentation if you want the explanation. You are wrong about what that option does. You don't need it. You don't want it. Get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @cfr! I would have never found that mistake. Write it as an answer if you want me to accept it. Otherwise I'll just update the question.

Comment: In the interests of keeping the questions and answers separate ... ;).

Comment: `pagenumbering` ... you are using it very very very weird. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192870/how-to-use-pagenumbering-in-the-document and http://golatex.de/welche-seitenzahl-hat-das-inhaltsverzeichnis-t13474.html

Comment: I updated pagenumbering. I start with `Roman` and change to `arabic` after the index.

Comment: cfr is absolutely right, your `\cite...`s are really clumsy. You should use `biblatex`'s facilities to define cite commands and their output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove

```
refsection=chapter
```

Otherwise, Biblatex assumes you will use a separate bibliography for each chapter. You can still have an outer bibliography, but it will only include things cited not in any chapter (before the first `\chapter` command, basically). The idea is that you then use `\printbibliography` inside each chapter, to print the chapter-specific sources.

In addition, you want to load `hyperref` as the *last* package, unless you know something should be loaded later. The notable case is `cleveref`, which must be loaded after `hyperref`. That's the only common exception to the `hyperref`-last policy I'm aware of.

But note that it would be much better to use Biblatex's facilities to define your custom citation commands. I'm not sure about the compatibility of `breakcites`, either (I've never used it).

You should not have to select German at the start of the document as you've specified it as the default.