# (! Missing number, treated as zero.) only when opening /section ? So confused

Tags: errors, formatting

I'm a beginner and I understand this is a basic error, however after 45mins of googling nothing I found is the same as my error and no fixes are useable.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{NAME}

\author{NAME}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{Arabic}

\section{Test}

test

\end{document}
```

I get an error at the last line `\end{document}` that tells me I should have a number? So this seems to be some type of formatting issue, google tells me I misplaced a bracket, but.. i have no brackets.

Comment: `arabic`. not `Arabic`

Comment: I suggest to close this as a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192870/how-to-use-pagenumbering-in-the-document), this might be just a simple typo, but the `\newpage` is also not correct. The explanation is in the linked answer.

Comment: Sorry I've been following a guide at latex-tutorial.com, brand new to this.

Comment: Sorry but I am reading through your link and the code newpage doesn't appear anywhere there?

Comment: Search for clearpage. Actually, `\newpage` is a command a user shouldn't need to use at all. If you are using it often, something is dodgy.

Comment: Do you really want the first page to be zero and the next to be 1?

Comment: Isn't that standard? The first page is just supposed to be the title.

Comment: @Alex Typographically, that title (not cover) has page number one. LaTeX f\*cks up here by resetting the page number to one later on. Thirty year old bug people are used to now.

Comment: @Johannes_B ?..

Answer (score 1):

I think what the author of the tutorial wanted to show might have been the following. The title on its own page, that page not having a page number and the next page starting with one. That is LaTeX default with the `titlepage` option.

[image: alexPagenumbering]

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}

\title{Life of Walter Wombat}
\author{Carl Capybara}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\section{Hello Little Duck}

beautiful story

\end{document}
```