# Start page-numbering of report from title-page

Tags: page-numbering

I have noticed that while making a document of the report-type, the title page is basically set to page-number 0, i.e. pages are numbered from one beginning from the  next page.

Consider for instance this MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{My Report}
\author{A.U. Thor}
\begin{document}
\maketitle % Title page should be page number 1

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext
\chapter{An Overview}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

In the image below, I have left out the title page, but notice that the next page where the first chapter begins is labelled as page 1, instead of page 2 which I would prefer.

How do I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208208/37907 shows an explanation. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280/37907 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation show simple ways of doing the titlepage by hand. For a simple fix, you could do `\setcounter{page}{2}` right *after* the `titlepage` environment.

Comment: Or have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464943/37907

Comment: Is there any news here?