# Fancyhdr - Begin pagination with 2

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, page

I am trying to create a document using LaTeX, and the requirements of my university are very strict. The pagination has to be on the top right corner, no number on the titlepage, the second page starting with roman number 2 (II).

I got the part with the top right thanks to fancyhdr, but I can't manage to start with II instead of I.

This is my code so far:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[R]{\thepage}%
    }
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464939/37907

Answer (score 1):

On your first page this should do the job :

```
   \pagenumbering{roman}\setcounter{page}{2}
```

Then when you have to get back to arabic numbers, just do :

```
   \pagenumbering{arabic}
```